# Doing a group sum in one excel cell (pivot, but don't want to use pivot)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have tried using the textjoin function to do this, but can't quite figure it out. I have a dynamic range with the following:

```
Product Problem Type
A       Type1
A       Type2
A       Type1
A       Type1
B       Type2
B       Type2
B       Type3
C       Type3
C       Type1
C       Type2
D       Type3
D       Type3
E       Type1
```

I can very easily do a group by sum (much like SQL) in a separate column, summing Type1 and Type2 (dont want to sum Type3) by Product type. My goal is to create **one** cell that looks like this (not sure if it is possible with regular excel formulas)

"A-4, B-2, C2, E-1". Essentially it finds unique product types and sums the Type1 and Type2 by product, in one cell. Is it possible?

This formula will return distinct product values into one cell with the number 4 next to each letter because A has 4 type1/type2.. Note: If I create a 'Total' column and put the groupby formula in there, I can get this to work by using B2:B14&D2:D14 at the end of the formula instead of the sum(countif) part.

```
  {=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(MATCH(B2:B14, B2:B14, 0)=MATCH(ROW(B2:B14), ROW(B2:B14)), B2:B14&SUM(COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,{"Type1","Type2"})), ""))}
```

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to count, not sum.

Comment: I see this as easily accomplished with a 'helper' column to assist uniqueness and count suffix but unreasonably complicated without one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming products span `Col A` & problems span `Col B`. 
This is making use of `Col D` and will put your output on cell `D1` when complete. If you have data in Col D, change the code to make use of a different column.

You will need to adjust the 3rd line to reflect your sheet name (swap `Sheet3` with your sheet name and leave the quotes

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Zero()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
Dim Product As Range, MyString As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws
        .Range("A1:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , .Range("D1"), True

            For Each Product In .Range("D2:D" & .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
                MyString = MyString & Product & "-" & (Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("A:A"), Product.Value, .Range("B:B"), "Type1") + _
                                                                              Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("A:A"), Product.Value, .Range("B:B"), "Type2")) & ", "
            Next Product

        .Range("D1:D" & .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("D1") = Left(MyString, Len(MyString) - 2)
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```